# Why only the first value is written to the variable

Tags: javascript

I want to get the properties of an object and call a function depending on the property. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
let page = {};
Object.keys(product.details).forEach((k) => {
  console.log(k)
  switch (k) {
    case 'description':
      page.add(getDescription());
      break;
    case 'comment':
      page.add(getComment());
      break;
    case 'subDescription':
      page.add(getSubDescription());
      break;
  }
});
console.log(page);
```

My object:

```
{
  about: 'text',
  description: 'text',
  comment: 'text',
  subDescription: 'text'
}
```

What do I get in the console:

```
about
description
...\src\views\partials\product\description.hbs
```

Why is only the first function called, and the rest not? What's my mistake?

Comment: `page.add` is not a function.

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Maheer Ali What for? Functions getDescription, getComment, getSubDescription return paths to files. But for some reason only the first one works

Comment: Can you show us your desired output ?

Comment: if the object has all the keys? and not doing anything with the value? why loop? get item has the complexity of O(1) for objects so the loop is an overkill.

Comment: @Jared Smith page.add did not write the path to my file from the function, and this led to a crash

Comment: Which object is *"My object"* exactly? `product` or `product.details` or `page`? Currently `page` doesn't have an `add` method. What does it do?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess - maybe **page.add()** simply doesn't exist.

**products.about** is the first key in your object - so inside the forEach loop you get

`console.log(k)` -> about -> nothing else

the next key is **description**
`console.log(k)` -> description -> now it tries to execute `page.add(getDescription());`
because it's defined in the switch-block. In case that function doesn't exist it will crash here.

Comment: hank you, I realized my big mistake(

Answer (score 0):

`page.add` is not defined unless you added it to the Object.prototype or declared it within your object, but thats totally unnecessary.

Use something like this, to make it more easy to handle. Why would you use functions to get values from an Object with the same key?

```
const page = {}

for (let key in product.details) {
  console.log(key) // returns about, comment, description, ....
  page[key] = product.details[key]
}

console.log(page)

/* console.log(page) returns
{
  about: "text"
  comment: "text"
  description: "text"
  subDescription: "text"
}
*/
```